# Cyclicality in time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

The high amount of cyclicality in the `lynx` time series makes it very difficult to model with `ets` and `auto.arima`.

```r
library(forecast)
library(fpp2)

data(lynx)

train <- subset(lynx, end = length(lynx) - 20) # hold-out last 20 years

ets_mod <- ets(train)
arima_mod <- auto.arima(train)

fc_ets <- forecast(ets_mod, h=20)
fc_arima <- forecast(arima_mod, h=20)
fc_naive <- naive(train, h=20)

accuracy(fc_ets, lynx)
accuracy(fc_arima, lynx) # winner
accuracy(fc_naive, lynx)

autoplot(fc_arima) + autolayer(tail(lynx,20)) # poor fit
```

[image]

Questions:

1. Are there other methods that I should try in the `forecast` package?
2. How do I change the legend in autoplot() and autolayer() to show "ARIMA Forecast" and "Actual"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic time series problem and there are lots of papers on it (see [Tong JRSSA 1977](https://doi.org/10.2307/2345278) for an early discusson).

You could transform the series (set lambda = 0.5 for example) and you will get slightly better ARIMA results. But the main problem is that the cycles are of unpredictable length, so any model you produce will struggle to capture the aperiodic cycles. That is why the ARIMA prediction intervals are wide and approach constant values (to cover the possibility of peaks or troughs).

You will need to use a nonlinear model to get anything better than that. See [Kajitani et al JF 2005](https://doi.org/10.1002/for.940) for one such model.

To answer your second question:

```
autoplot(train) + 
  autolayer(fc_arima, series="ARIMA Forecast") + 
  autolayer(tail(lynx,20), series="Actual")
```